# Don't get access to virtual host on Apache

Tags: macos, apache-http-server

I created a virtual host using Apache. The normal `127.0.0.1` or `localhost` works, it get a successful output.
But on input the name of the virtual host, I get an error message.

```
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access / on this server.
```

Here are my settings:

**hosts**

```
127.0.0.1   example.com
127.0.0.1   www.example.com
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
```

**httpd.conf**

```
[...]
# Virtual hosts
Include /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
[...]
```

**httpd-vhosts.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName localhost
DocumentRoot "/Library/WebServer/Documents"
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host.example.com
    DocumentRoot "/Library/Webserver/Documents/example/"
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    ErrorLog "/Library/Webserver/Documents/enetworks/example.com-error_log"
    CustomLog "/Library/Webserver/Documents/enetworks/example.com-access_log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

**example.com-error_log**

```
127.0.0.1:50922] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /Library/Webserver/Documents/example/
```

Could anyone say me, where's the problem?
Thanks, ;).